# Can we classify the general linear maps such that for a fixed matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ the conjuagation action fixes the first column?

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, matrices, matrix-analysis, path-connected

Let $A \in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ be fixed. Let us consider the conjugation action by $G \in GL_n(\mathbb R)$, i.e., $G^{-1}AG$. I would like to see a way to identify the matrices such that the action fixes the first column of $A$. That is, what can we say about the set
\begin{align*}
\mathcal E = \{G \in GL_n(\mathbb R): G^{-1}AGe_1 = a_1\},
\end{align*}
where $e_1$ is the standard basis vector and $a_1$ is the first column of $A$. In particular, is the set connected? Let us **exclude** the trivial case: $A$ is a multiple of $I$ or $-I$.

If we define a linear map $\phi: M_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^n$ by $X \mapsto (XA-AX)e_1$, then $\mathcal E = \ker(\phi) \cap GL_n(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One  can not say that  $\mathcal E$  is  always connected.

For  $n=3, $(and  similarly $n>3$)  let  $A$  be  a matrix  with  $a_{i1}=1,\quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\} $

Then $\mathcal E$ contains  the  identity  matrix whose determinant is  $1$ and it also contains the  following  matrix  with determinant $-1$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0  \end{pmatrix}$$

According  to  the previous  version  of  your  question about the  (semi)group  structure  of  $\mathcal E$, observe that  if you can prove that $\mathcal E$ is  a  semigroup then it is a  group, too. Because  the inverse of  a every matrix  $G$,  can  be written in the  form of a   polynomial in $G$.

I  think that $\mathcal E$  is  not  a  Lie group  because it  is  contained in a  sub vector  space $F$, the  kernel you  mentioned,  whose dimension is  equal to  the  dimension of  $G$. Moreover $Exp(F)$  is  contained  in $\mathcal E$  But in general  case,  $F$  is  not  a  Lie  algebra with the  commutator  Lie  bracket.  [Please  see  the  comment  by Corbennick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313136/a-lie-group-which-is-sat-in-its-lie-algebra)

Comment: I was in mind probably $\mathcal E$ would have two (or more) components corresponding to the positive determinant and negative determinant. Would you comment on how many components would $\psi(\mathcal E)$ have, where $\psi: B \mapsto B^{-1}AB$ provided $A$ has a real eigenvalue? In this case, the positive and negative determinant would be mapped into the same image.

Comment: @user9527  That is  an  interesting question(the  number  of  components). i have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @user9527  In fact one  can  generalize your interesting  question in the following  form: is there a  linear subvector  space  of  $M_n(\mathbb{R}$ which intersect  $GL_n(\mathbb{R}$ in  more than 2 components?Is there an  example of  this  situation with codimension is equal $n$?(In your  question that kernel has codimension n)

Comment: In $2\times 2$ matrices the matrices of the form $[[x,y],[y,x]]$ intersect $GL_2$ in the subset of the plane with equation $xy\neq 0$, which has 4 components.

Comment: @user9527 Yes. In size $n$, in the subspace of upper triangular matrices, there are $2^n$ components of invertible matrices.

Comment: @YCor: Could you comment on the connected components of $\psi(\mathcal E)$ in my first comment? Thanks.

Comment: @YCor  Is there  a  Lie  subgroup  $G$  of  $GL(n,\mathbb{R}$  which  is  sat is  a  subvector  space $F\subset  M_n(\mathbb{R})$  such  that $dim G=dim F$  but $F$ is  not  a  Lie  subalgebra?(I  discussed on this  question in the  linked post).

Comment: @AliTaghavi I don't know what you mean by "which is sat is"

Comment: @YCor  I  mean "inclusion, subset". I  mean that  $G$ is  a  subset of  $F$.

Comment: So, $G\to F$ is an immersion between manifolds of the same dimension, so has an open image; $F$ is the the lie algebra of $G$.